# How to added div with direct and delegated using jQuery

Tags: jquery, click, keydown

I have a div, when click on it, it will switch to contenteditor...

```
.attr('contenteditable',true)
```

If the enter key pressed, it will add a div below.

Please see the examples: http://jsfiddle.net/UserNaN/9yFbL/

But the problem here is that when a new div is added, I can't get these events delegated click/keydown to work.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Use `on()`'s delegation methods. You also have a problem because you're adding multiple elements with the same id which is not allowed in HTML. You'll get unpredictable results with that.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I manually added multiple elements with the same `#text` and the div id work is fine http://jsfiddle.net/UserNaN/9yFbL/1/

Comment: I'm telling you that you will have a problem with this in the very near future - like when you get ready to submit the information in those divs to a database via AJAX. Regardless of manual or automated addition. http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H93.html

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. Please give me a specific examples of `on()`'s delegation methods!

Comment: Added an answer that should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified version using `.on()` for delegation events. All of the id's have been changed to classes and some un-needed functions have been removed. - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/9yFbL/5/

```
$('body').on('click', '.container .content', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('.text').removeAttr('contenteditable'); // not sure why this div was editable and then have the attribute moved to its parent
    $(this).attr('contenteditable',true).focus();
});
$('body').on('keydown', '.container .content', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('.container').append('<div class="content"></div>');
        $(this).parent('.container').find('.content:last').append('<div class="text">ADDED</div>');
        $(this).removeAttr('contenteditable');
        $(this).parent().find('.content:last').attr('contenteditable',true).focus();
    }
});
```

If I was able to take a little more time on this I would probably be able to make it a little more elegant.